# Python3: StringIO and Elementree encoding

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, elementtree, stringio

With migration to Python 3 xml.etree.ElementTree's write() doesn't work as expected.

I need to make the following code work with Python3:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
fileobj = StringIO()

tree.write(fileobj, encoding="utf-8")
```

The problem with py3 is that it treats fileobj as bytes and therefore fails to write it to StringIO. Then after checking [ElementTree docutmentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) it appears I have to use `encoding='unicode'` and this works just fine in py3 but fails with py2.

Now, it there a way to make it work with both py2 and py3 or do I have to use io.BytesIO as a workaround for py3, or shall I use different encoding based on python version?

What is the best solution here?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've decided to use io.BytesIO for both py2 and py3